# Make an array divisible by n?

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

Is there a way to make it contain elements only divisible by 3 (or n)? So in the above example `g` would be removed as it's left over from a division of 3?

---

EDIT

I want amount of elements divisible by 3.

Comment: You can `for` loop through it and see if `$i%3==0` **EDIT:** count the values, divide the count by 3, round the result to the bottom and then multiply the count by the result and only take values till the count times the rounded result

Comment: Do you mean the amount of elements should be dividable by 3?

Comment: Yes I want amount of elements divisible by 3.

Comment: So, you want to *remove* elements until the *length* is divisible by 3?  What if there are only 2 elements to begin with, would that go to 0?

Comment: With the current array you have, what would be the expected output?

Comment: this looks like a interview question or a quiz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `array_slice()`, `count()` and modulus (`%`) to get the array evenly divisible:

```
$arr_length = count($arr);
$new_arr = array_slice($arr, 0, $arr_length - ($arr_length % 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the *length* to be divisible by 3 and you want to *remove* elements until that happens.  `array_slice` can help you out here.

```
$to_remove = count($arr) % 3;
if($to_remove > 0){
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 0, -$to_remove);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. I like it. Short, easy to read and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

@panthro simply try with for loop like below and use array_pop()

```
<?php
    $arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    if(count($arr) % 3 != 0){
        $remainder = count($arr) % 3;
        for($i=0;$i < $remainder;$i++){
            array_pop($arr);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr); //final array divisible by 3
```